Расширить раздел диска в LVM
Всем привет. Есть раздел диска /dev/xx - он уже в LVM 10GB. Есть не размеченное пространство 30GB. Как мне расширить /dev/xx на размер не размеченного пространства?
При создании неразмеченного пространства создается отдельный раздел /dev/xx1 с 30GB. Пытался его добавить в LVM, то есть создаю PV, затем группу томов, затем LV. И они как бы объединяются но по отдельности. То есть получается два диска в одной точке монтирования. Подскажите как быть?

создаю PV, затем группу томов, затем LV зачем создавать VG и новый LV, когда вам нужно расширить на новый PV уже существующую группу томов?
